# is it possible to interact with two different entities in CoreData at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have to Entities in my CoreData, object one is a "temp" entity to download updates, Entity two is my main active entity.

When I am downloading data to entity 1 off the main thread, I seem to "hang" when I try and access entity 2.

Is this an expected interaction?

Thanks for the help (Sorry if I asked this in a confusing way)

Comment: Multi threading and core data is not straightforward (it's not that hard, you just need to ensure each thread had its own managed object context) - have you done this?

Comment: and by entity you mean NSManagedObjectContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Core Data on multiple threads, the standard practice is to create a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread using the same persistent store coordinator.